# A simple event driven batch processing

Tags: architecture, hdfs, event-driven-design

First of all, I wanted to gather some information one how a simple event driven architecture works in real life. If this question is not suitable in here. please kindly let me know where I can ask these kind of questions.

Here is my usecase:
My company has two department, Department A provides the data in HDFS to Department B, starts the process and generate final report. Schedule example
Department A starts the process at 11:00 AM
Department B starts the process at 05:00 PM

My questions is, How department B can starts the process as soon as data available from Department A.

My initial though is to have a periodic data availability checks on department B

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a task collector in some queue RabbitMQ or Kafka that has signal that Data is available and complete in ingestion layer
2. Start a producer Kafka with HDFS as Source that producing streams for Department A
3. A consumer Kafka in Dept B is receiving the Dept A data continuously.
4. The data in Dept B Kafka will be json or Avro
5. You will have to write some consumer Kafka in Dept B that transform AVRO into Structured form and the insert in HDFS
6. Write some Unit test to validate data in Dept B to test data